# Aptana and eclipse rails: how to select an application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hy,

Im trying to use this "script/generate cell ShoppingCart display" but in the error is showing me "C:/Users/Totty/workspace/test1/" and test1 is not the project i want to add the cell.

I want to add the cell to test2, how do i do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to click on any folders/files in the Ruby Explorer view and the project will be in focus, and the Rake Tasks view will show `Current Ruby Project: test2`. After that you can add the cell into the desired project.

hope this helps =)

Comment: now i found it out, there is a button near the console that let you select the current application.